# changing menu background-color when at top of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu which animates into view (from the top) when user scrolls up. And animates up (off screen) when user scrolls down. However, I want the background of the navigation to be black when user is at the top of the page, and white after they are a certain distance from the top.

html-snippet (working code)

```
...
function hasScrolled() {
if($( window ).width() > 768) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {

        // Scroll Down
        $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');

    } else {

        // Scroll Up
        if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
     }
    } else {
    $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
```

html

```
<nav id="s-nav" class="row nav-down">
  ... nav menu ...
</nav>
```

css

```
#s-nav { 
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
background-color: #fff;
top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%;
transition: top 0.5s ease;
}
#s-nav.nav-up { top: -75px; }
```

Comment: Can you provide any working `snippet` or `fiddle` ?

Comment: Majority of content is created through wordpress. Snippet doesn't recognize the code when I try

Comment: as you are switching classes while scrolling, then you can use those classes for switching `bg-color` as well.

Comment: Right, but all I can do is change the background when it animates off screen and on. I want it to change when the user is at the top of the page as opposed to the rest of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 200) {
    $("#s-nav").addClass('white_bg');
  } else $("#s-nav").removeClass('white_bg');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  height: 1000px;
}
.nav-down {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  color: #ff0;
}
.white_bg{
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="s-nav" class="row nav-down">
  ... nav menu ...
</nav>
```

Comment: An additional question, can it be done so that the css isn't hardcoded, but instead apply a css class? as well how to add a second class to another inner div. (etc. when the background is white I ned to change text to black)